# how to validate l2t-paper-color custom element in polymer js

Tags: polymer

i am using l2t-paper-color element and i cant get to call its validate function can anyone tell me the workaround or the solution for this.

```
<l2t-paper-color id="Color" required auto-validate></l2t-paper-color>
```

this is not working.
Any way to make this work or how to validate.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/Link2Twenty/l2t-paper-color/elements/l2t-paper-color) of component `l2t-paper-color` there is no property `auto-validate` and `required`. If you want to validate, I suggest you to call 
the `value-changed` event and do the validation there.

HTML:

`<l2t-paper-color value="{{color}}" on-value-changed="_onValueChanged"></l2t-paper-color>`

JS:

```
_onValueChanged(e){
  console.log(e.detail.value);
  //Validation code...
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/Sahero/pen/vJXZOO?editors=0000

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use iron-form? If so the Component needs to implement [iron-form-element-behavior](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form-element-behavior/v1.0.7/behaviors/Polymer.IronFormElementBehavior). If its not your own Component you have to write a wrapper which implements the behavior.